# how to make the connection between group shape id in Visio?

Tags: xml, shapes, visio

I am facing a problem when I using Xpath to read the Visio xml file (.vdx).
I create a custom stencil by grouping two sub shapes. For instance Shape A is consist of two sub shapes b and c. When I create two instances of A like A1(consist of b1 and c1) and A2(consist of b2 and c2). The connect tag in XML doesn't show the relationship of A1 and B1. Instead, it just shows b1 and b2 are connected.

Please take a look at the xml below, image the shape id for A1 is 1 (sub shape id is 3, 4), A2 is 2 (sub shape id is 5, 6)

```
<Shpaes>
   <Shape ID ="1" Name="ShapeA1" Type="Group" Master="12"> 
     <Shapes>
        <Shape ID ="3" Type="Group" Master="12">
        <Shape ID ="4" Type="Group" Master="12">         
     </Shapes>
   </Shape>

   <Shape ID ="2" Name="ShapeA2" Type="Group" Master="12"> 
     <Shapes>
        <Shape ID ="5" Type="Group" Master="12">
        <Shape ID ="6" Type="Group" Master="12">         
     </Shapes>
   </Shape>

  <Shape ID ="7" Name="Connector" Type="Group" Master="12"> 
  </Shape>
</Shapes> 

<Connects>
 <Connect ToPart="3" ToCell="PinX" ToSheet="3" FromPart="12" FromCell="BeginX"     FromSheet="7"/>
 <Connect ToPart="3" ToCell="PinX" ToSheet="5" FromPart="12" FromCell="EndX" FromSheet="7"/>
</Connects>
```

I want the ToSheet Attribute in Connect is "1" and "2" which represent the group shape id rather than its subshape id.

Please let me know what should I do in Visio

Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

When the group shape is the generic hidden group that provides no geometry (what you get when you select the subshapes and simply hit ctrl-G), it can be very easy to inadvertently connect the subshapes rather than the outer group shape.  That appears to be what happened in your case.

The problem is often that the generic hidden group shape's SelectMode is always set to 1 (select group first), which allows the user to select (or glue to) subshapes of the group.  Setting the SelectMode of the group to 0 (select group only) solves this problem.  SelectMode can be changed directly in the shapesheet window or the Behavior dialog (available in the Developer tab in Visio 2010 and later).